# How with the help of the similarity function to replace values by determination of similarity of one value to another in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, similarity

Kind day, my problems connected with a large number of typos in the name of the firms/companies and I want to unite them strictly by certain names happens so on one company name of 20-30 similar names. I work with PostgreSQL 12.7. For example one company its only right name (OOO "VLADI") and the deformed values because of typos, and so with one hundred different firms / companies: "VLADI", LTD "VLAD", "vladi", "vlad", etc. I thought to use the similarity function for determination of similarity of one value to another and then on the basis of similarity to rewrite data on only right (OOO "VLADI"). The table of "DataB" at me in it the Compania column and also the temporary table compare with the need column (in this column the correct names of firms are specified). How to make so from the Compania column values would independently be pulled out and compared to the need column in the temporary table compare and replaced. Thanks to the user of "Mike" and "Roman Konoval" I could collect this, but it doesn't work as it is necessary.

Here examples of the table:

Table No. 1 the table DataB (what is)

| CountryCompanii | Compania |
| --- | --- |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLAD" |
| DE | OOO VLADI |
| DE | OOO VLAD |
| DE | "VLADI" |
| DE | "VLAD" |
| DE | LTD "VLAD" |
| DE | VLADI в германии |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |
| GB | LTD "LILYT" |
| GB | LTD "LiLYT" |
| GB | LTD "Lilyt" |
| GB | LTD "LyLiT" |

Table No. 2 the table DataB (what has to be)

| CountryCompanii | Compania |
| --- | --- |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| DE | OOO "VLADI" |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |
| GB | ООО "LILYT" |

Also there is a script:

```
WITH compare (need) AS
     (VALUES ('ООО "LILYT"'),('ООО VLADI')
),
UPDATE (Compania)  as(
SELECT Compania, 'сравниваем с ' || need, similarity(Compania, need)
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY need ORDER BY similarity(Compania, need) DESC)
AS "Ранжирование результатов"
FROM "DataB" CROSS JOIN "compare"
WHERE similarity(Compania, need) >0.25
)
UPDATE "DataB" SET Compania = need 
FROM compare
```

Help because a lot of time is spent on manual edition if there are alternatives on more effectively, then I will be glad to learn about them.
And in advance I apologize for the knowledge of English.

Comment: The `similarity` function does not consider the big round thing in the Latin alphabet to be similar to big round thing in the Cyrillic alphabet.  While that might be "good enough" for you current example, it is hard to see tis being good enough for real world data.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic update you are trying to do looks like a disaster to me.  While you can have the system propose changes to make, you really need to have a human with some subject-matter expertise review the changes to make sure they are sensible before applying them.  So what you really need to implement is interfaces to quickly review and approve the proposed changes.

But with the statement you show, there are multiple problems.  You define a common table expression named "UPDATE" (a truly horrible name, I'll call it "to_update_with" instead) but then you never use that CTE, rather you go back to using the first CTE you defined, "compare".

```
UPDATE "DataB" SET Compania = need 
FROM compare
```

In that update, there is no WHERE clause, so every row of "DataB" gets "compania" set to every value of "need" from "compare".  Of course only row from "compare" can actually end up getting stored in each row of "DataB", but which one that is arbitrary and is certainly not the one you want to use, other than by chance.  You need a WHERE clause, which ties the value being updated to the correct value to update it with.  Of course you can't have such a WHERE with "compare", as it only has single column.  That is why you need to use the to_update_with table instead.

And with that to_update_with CTE, you assign the first column of it a name in parentheses when declaring it `UPDATE (Compania)`, but it has 4 columns, so what are the names of the other 3 columns supposed to be?  One of them has a name assigned by a different method, giving it a very long non-English (and non-Latinate) name in the AS, but for the other two it is left up to PostgreSQL to just guess what a good name for them would be.  Also, it is possible for this CTE to return more than one row for a given compania if more than two "accepted" names are within 0.25, which is possible although doesn't occur in your specific example. If there were more than one, you would then be left with uncertainty about what one would get used in the UPDATE. You defined a dense_rank column.  Presumably you wanted to use this to filter to keep only the best single option, but you never actually applied that filtering.  But I'm pretty sure you partitioned wrong in the dense_rank, you want to rank the accepted names by how similar they are for each existing company name, while you are doing it the other way around.

So put it all together and you get something like this:

```
WITH compare (need) AS
     (VALUES ('ООО "LILYT"'),('ООО VLADI')
),
to_update_with as( 
  select compania, need from (
    SELECT Compania, need, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY compania ORDER BY similarity(Compania, need) DESC) AS "rank"
    FROM "DataB" CROSS JOIN "compare"
    WHERE similarity(Compania, need) >=0.25 
  ) foo where rank=1
)
update "DataB" set compania=need 
from to_update_with 
where to_update_with.compania="DataB".compania;
```

Although as I said at the beginning, you probably shouldn't actually do it this way.